# Eigenvectors of matrices which commute with a projection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Just a quick question. Cant seem to prove it or find any relevant references! Maybe it's really simple :\ Is the following statement true (for square matrices of the same finite dimension)?

If there exists no simultaneous right and left eigenvectors of M, then there exists no (besides $P=0$ or $P=I$) projection matrix $P=P^2$ such that $[P,M]=0$.

Thanks for the help/potential counter example!

Comment: With $P=0$ or $P=I$, we always get $[P,M]=0$. So you want $P$ nontrivial as well to avoid silly counterexamples like that.

Comment: Oops, I meant to include a statement discounting these trivial solutions! thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 1):

A simultaneous right/left eigenvector for $A$ is $x\neq 0$ such that $Ax=\lambda $ and $x^TA=\mu x^T$, i.e. $A^Tx=\mu x$. That is a common eigenvector of $A$ and $A^T$. I assume the coefficients belong to a field $K$.

1) Here is a $2\times 2$ counterexample:
$$
A=P=\pmatrix{1&1\\0&0}.
$$
Clearly, $A$ and $P$ commute, and $P$ is idempotent ($P^2=P$). The two eigenvalues of $A$ and $A^T$ are $0$ and $1$. And we have, denoting the canonical basis of $K^2$ by $\{e_1,e_2\}$:
$$
\ker A=K(e_1-e_2)\quad\ker(A-I_2)=Ke_1\quad \ker A^T=Ke_2\quad\ker (A^T-I_2)=K(e_1+e_2).
$$
So $A$ and $A^T$ don't share any nonzero eigenvector.

2) Here is a $4\times 4 $ counterexample with $P$ self-adjoint + idempotent:
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0}\qquad P=\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0}.
$$
Clearly, $P$ does commute with $A$. Yet the only eigenvalue of $A$ and $A^T$ is $0$. And the only solution to $Ax=A^Tx=0$ is $x=0$.

Comment: Hm okay yea I see. I guess I was looking for a case where the common eigenvector of $A$ and $A^T$ wasnt the zero vector... Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @jeremy Hmm. Please consider the logic of this again. What this proves is: your implication $Left \Rightarrow Right$ is false. By showing that the contrapositive is false, which would be: if there exists $P$... then there exists a nontrivial common eigenvector.... My examples show that we can have such a $P$ without the conclusion that there exists a nontrivial common eigenvector.

Comment: okay great! Now what if we add yet another additional assumption that P must be an orthogonal projection? ...I noticed your 2 by 2 example wont hold now. Thanks for the help and time!

Comment: @jeremy That's precisely why I added the second counterexample. Here $P$ is an orthogonal projection.